# Wildcard SSL certificate for a domain that may already have other certificates setup - any issues with that?

Tags: security, ssl-certificate

I'm thinking installing a wildcard cert for a site we are migrating from another company's server to our server.

The domain has many other subdomains, and I'm guessing some of them of single domain cert's on them, but they are all hosted on other servers - the cert I install would be the only one on the server.

Can anyone confirm for me that this setup is advisable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, there should be no problem with this setup. Only the (sub)domains on the new server will use the wildcard cert. All the others will use local certs. In fact, since it's a wildcard cert, you could copy it across all the servers.

Comment: Using the certificate on multiple servers will lower the security by increasing the chances for the certificate to be compromised.

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici while this is true, most vendors will allow for unlimited duplicate requests of a wildcard if you are licensed to use it on multiple servers. This will allow the same "certificate" to be used while having separate private keys on each.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate is local to the web server using it. There isn't something that connects back to the CA to make sure only one website is using the certificate you want to use. For kicks and giggles, you could have 100 different certificates for the same domain on the same machine and round robin them all if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

There is not problem in this usage, but the wildcard certificate issued for `*.example.com` will work only for `<subdomain>.example.com` and not for `<sub-subdomain>.<subdomain>.example.com`.